# Query to fetch Meta Data Information about type of objects in a schema in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have  a query as below .

I want to have a result-set to identify count of objects grouped by the type of object (table, external table, view, stored procedure, function etc.) for all the schemas in a specific database in Snowflake

```
WITH
CTE_AN_SCHEMA_SF
AS
(
select catalog_name as database,
       schema_name,
       RIGHT (schema_name,1) AS SCHEMA_TYPE,
       schema_owner,
       created,
       last_altered
from information_schema.schemata
WHERE schema_name <> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' AND schema_name <> 'PUBLIC'
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_AN_SCHEMA_SF WHERE SCHEMA_TYPE = 'P'
```

Comment: Information about each object type is held in a separate view in the information schema, so you would need to query each view (TABLE, VIEW, EXTERNAL_TABLE, etc) and union the results together - or otherwise combine them to get the result you want

Comment: ok, What all objects can one Snowflake schema contain: 1. Tables 2. Views 3. Materialized Views 4. Stored Procedures 5. Functions 6. Tasks 7. Snow Pipes  Anything missed?

Comment: Why not just check the information_schema documentation?